# Httplib - Check if connection is open

Tags: python, httplib

I'm opening connections to a server and sending chunk-encoded HTTP posts. The server that I connect to closes connections if no data has been sent in a minute, so I would like to check if the connection is still open as I write data.

The connections are initialized with something like:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url, 80)
conn.putrequest('POST', '/')
conn.putheader('Host', hosturl)
conn.putheader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
conn.putheader('Connection', 'close')
conn.endheaders()
```

And data gets written with:

```
conn.send('{msglen}\r\n{msg}\r\n'.format(msglen=msglen, msg=msg))
```

Is there a way to tell if this connection is open? I noticed the exception `httplib.NotConnected`, but if I run:

```
conn.close()
conn.send(data)
```

The exception does not get thrown.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that

```
conn.sock != None
```

will indicate weather it's connected or not.

Comment: Close! However it looks like if the server shuts down the connection, the httplib still keeps the socket instance.

Comment: :-[. So presumably conn.sock.send and conn.sock.recv also do not create exceptions?